# Отправка файла в БД - PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, redbeanphp

проблема заключается в том, что когда я использую ajax, то у меня не загружаются файлы на хостинг и не добавляется имя файла в БД, но при этом текст который пользователь водит, добавляется в БД. Если же я не использую ajax, то всё работает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема!!!!!! (Может быть такое, что я не туда вставил php код отправки файла, в этом я нуб).

**Очень нужна помощь!!!**

**PHP**

```
<form id="form-post-feed" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="post-feed">
        <textarea name="text" type="text" rows="1" placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
        <input id="postUploadFileInput" class="post-upload-file-input" type="file" name="image"></input>
        <label for="postUploadFileInput" class="post-upload-file-label"></label>
        <button class="post-send" type="submit" id="send" name="send"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**post-script.php** (Работает с БД и файлом, а ajax на него ссылается)

```
    $data = $_POST;
    $errors = array();

    if( empty($errors) )
    {
        $posts = R::dispense('posts');
        $posts->text = $data['text'];
        $posts->image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $user->ownPostsList[] = $posts;
        R::store($posts);
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'\post_image\\'.$_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    } else {
        echo '<p>Ошибка загрузки поста!</p>';
    }

    $response_post_feed = [
        "status" => true
    ];
    echo json_encode($response_post_feed);
```

**JS**

```
    $('#form-post-feed').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/post-script',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#form-post-feed').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if (data.status) {
                    console.log('OK');
                } else {
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**А вот PHP код, который отлично работает без AJAX**

```
    $data = $_POST;
    if (isset($data["send"])) {
        $errors = array();
        if( empty($errors) )
        {
            $posts = R::dispense('posts');
            $posts->text = $data['text'];
            $posts->image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $user->ownPostsList[] = $posts;
            R::store($posts);
            echo '<p>Вы отправили пост!</p>';
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'\post_image\\'.$_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        } else {
            echo '<p>Ошибка загрузки поста!</p>';
        }
    }

<form action="/posts" id="form-post-feed" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="post-feed">
        <textarea name="text" type="text" rows="1" placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
        <input id="postUploadFileInput" class="post-upload-file-input" type="file" name="image"></input>
        <label for="postUploadFileInput" class="post-upload-file-label"></label>
        <button class="post-send" type="submit" id="send" name="send"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('#form-post-feed').serialize()` не учитывает файлы. Это можно легко узнать путем гугления "ajax загрузка файлов"

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы подтолкнули меня на более длительное гугление и я нашел как правильно написать код!

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается всё просто! Нашел [ответ тут](https://overcoder.net/q/1294013/php-ajax-jquery-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82).

```
    $('#form-post-feed').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var file_data = $('#postUploadFileInput').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('image', file_data);
        form_data.append('text', $("#postText").val());

        $.ajax({
            url: '/post-script',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```